# Tanstack query with queryKey Undefined what better

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

What I need is to fetch data by using queryKey as a parameter and make some transformation of data after success with select. And `username` should be `string | undefined` since I want to handle `undefined` case in this component.

```js
interface Props {
  username: string | undefined
}

const fetchUser = (username: string): Promise<Object> => Promise.resolve({})

export function UserCard({ username }: Props) {
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ['markets', username],
    () => fetchUser(username), // <---- ts-error here
    {
      select: (data: Object): Object => {
        // ..
        return data
      },
    }
  )
  //..
}
```

But It's a problem that `username` might be `undefined`.

What I've tried to do is throw an error or reject so I will get data as `undefined`.

```js
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ['markets', username],
    () => {
      if (!username) return Promise.reject()
      return fetchUser(username)
    },
    {
      select: (data: Object): Object => {
        // ..
        return data
      },
    }
  )
```

But it's not good to have errors happen in development (and it's counterintuitive).

What next is to make `undefined` return from queryFn:

```js
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ['markets', username],
    () => username && fetchUser(username),
    {
      select: (data: Object | undefined): Object | undefined => {
        // ..
        if (!data) return undefined
        return data
      },
    }
  )
```

But I'm not sure this will be alright because the docs said like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KongH.png).

And this solution would be the recommended way as it has been introduced in docs, Dependent query.

```js
export function UserCard({ username }: Props) {
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ['markets', username],
    () => fetchUser(username), // but still ts-error 
    {
      select: (data: Object): Object => {
        // ..
        return data
      },
      enabled: username != undefined,
    }
  )
  //..
}
```

Yeah, It still has type errors. So I'm not sure what I've done wrong here maybe need to change function's parameter type. But I think it's not good to change it that way. Or maybe has another solution that I missed, or even my approach is wrong in the first place.

I'm very new to this and sorry for my bad English, thank you for advising in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`

Answer (score 0):

To stop queries from running when a dependency is not yet ready, the enabled option is what you want. But yes, TypeScript cannot know that `username` will be defined inside the queryFn, and technically, there are ways to bypass the enabled option, like calling `refetch` directly.

Rejecting the promise is the best way to go:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ['markets', username],
    () => {
      if (!username) return Promise.reject(new Error("invalid username"))
      return fetchUser(username)
    }, {
        enabled: !!username
    }
  )
```

I'm going into details here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script#type-safety-with-the-enabled-option